# GDB attach problems with /sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, exploit

Hi I had a little question.
I've been trying for hours to find a solution but I just do not get on.
I would like to use the gdb.attach function via pwntools.
But whenever I call this function also opens the gdb with the executable and also waits pwntools then on the gdb gives a feedback.
But in the GDB window goes then below only:

```
0x00007fbf014828be in __GI___libc_read (fd=0x0, buf=0x56139a7ee370, nbytes=0x1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
26 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: File or directory not found.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fbf0145f140: file ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S, line 120.
```

When I use the gdb.debug function I have no problems but unfortunately I also need the gdb.attach function.

This is the test code I use:

```
from pwn import*

p = process('bash')
gdb.attach(p,
'''
directory /home/pentester/Downloads/glibc-2.32/
set follow-fork-mode child
break execve
continue
''')
p.interactiv()
```

I have already downloaded the glibc sources but I don't know where to put them exactly.
I had them in the sources in the gdbinit reingepackt but unfortunately the problem is still there :(
Does one of you maybe have an idea how I can get the whole thing running?

Edit:
What I forgot to say is that the debugger seems to hang and pwntools searches in vain for the gdb.

Comment: there's a security-oriented stack: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't need Glibc sources, you've already successfully attached to a running process.  GDB defaults to wanting to show source, but `layout reg` or whatever will show asm.  Looks like bash was in the middle of a `read` system call, probably blocked on terminal input.  GDB then set the breakpoint, and resumed bash, I guess continuing the read system call it was blocked on.  When `bash` is invoked with stdin not being a TTY, it just makes read system calls to read commands.  (As opposed to using `select()` or `pselect6` system calls on a TTY)